# Jquery UI Autocomplete not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter

Im using Jquery widget Autocomplete.My data source  is a server-side script which returns JSON data.

```
$(function() {      
    $( "#supcode" ).autocomplete({
        source:"index.php/inventory/supcode",
        minLength: 1                    
    });
});
```

Im using MVC architecture (Codeigniter) and using following method in controller to return the JSON data,

```
function supcode()
{     
    $dataarray="";
    $data=$this->Inventorymodel->supcode();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And I am fetching the data in model using following function,

```
function supcode(){
$finresult="";
$this->db->select('name');
$query = $this->db->get('supplier');
$result=$query->result_array();

foreach($result as $row){
    $finresult[]=array(
        'name' => $row['name']
    );
}
return $finresult;
}
```

When I type a letter in the textbox filtering is not working and all the items are listed.What have I done wrong here? Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance....

Comment: I find `print_r()` helps a lot when looking at JSON code, print it like that and make sure your variables are all there and correct.

Comment: no its not working...I tried print_r(json_encode($data)) instead of echo json_encode($data) ..and same problem.Filtering is not working..

Comment: have you tested it in firefox json request response ?

Comment: Are you sure the request is made to the server ?

Comment: yes..it is made..and im getting the response ["abcd","efgh","klmn"] in firebug...all these three items are listed in the autocomplete list..and the problem is filtering is not working

Comment: doesn't it mean your PHP is code wrong?

Comment: Where are you applying your filter? All I see is a function that fetches everything and returns it into `$finresult`. You need some in-parameter to `supcode()` which you then can use to filter your results.

Comment: Jquery Autocomplete widget should filter the data.We dont have to do any filtering process..

Comment: @BasimSherif: *No*, the autocomplete widget does not filter the data when you use a remote data source. If you use a remote source *your server side code* is responsible for doing the filtering. This is right there in the documentation: "instead the request parameter "term" gets added to the URL, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete the filtering on the server side (as stated in the comments to the question by @Henrik) and the **Expected data format** needs to be an array of objects with `label` and `value` as the fields.

```
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

See this link [jQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete).